Mainnet contract deployment hangs
I am trying to deploy my solana mainnet contract but it stuck during deployment, will it reibursable? Can I cancel it as it is taking longer time?
Why it is stuck? Solana mainnet status is also good https://status.solana.com/

Use solana program deploy ./target/deploy/<program-name>.so with the following flags

--use-rpc if you have a custom RPC URL (solana config set -u <url>)
--with-compute-unit-price <micro-lamports> to add a priority fee
--buffer <buffer-address> to retry a previous deploy (run solana program show --buffers to find any open buffers from incomplete deploys)
--use-quic this has helped me sometimes (replace --use-rpc if you use this one)

Using these in tandem to both deploy & run retries should help get your program deployed :)

still it is taking too much time ad almost timedout every time, is there anyway to deploy fast

The above answer is right.
Let me share an example.
This is the best cmd I've seen for deploying contracts on mainnet.
solana program deploy --program-id /home/odmin/projects/solana-betting-contract/target/deploy/hamster_bet-keypair.json /home/odmin/projects/solana-betting-contract/target/deploy/hamster_bet.so --max-sign-attempts 1000 --with-compute-unit-price 100000 --buffer 4i9CLNWF1ntakuFFUnXLMt77sMHVcKuqa31abNgoHdYr

Please change your contract "so" file name from my cmd.
Because of the Solana mainnet issue, you will fail to deploy. In this case, type this again until you will success.
This command do not clean any history for last deploy.
